# How can I use a code or a script to lock my screen programmatically in Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I want to write code or a script to lock the PC when my C++ program receives a specific command from Ethernet.

Is there any way to show the Login screen from the command line? I want to lock the screen from a c++ code. Actually I want to do something like Ctrl + Alt + L programmatically (from a c++ code). Thanks

Edit: I found the way. For those who want to know, as Lubuntu uses LXDE desktop, it has some methods to do thing like it. The command for locking the screen is lxlock.

Comment: this can be found out by simply googling or visiting the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com)

Comment: What is your graphical environment? plain text? gnome? Yo have gnome-screensaver, but this is just for gnome... We need additional information

Comment: I actually use Lubuntu with LXDE desktop

Comment: Instead of editing your question, post your solution as an answer! (and accept is as the answer that solved your problem)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation. So I can't answer the question. I'm a newbie here:)

Comment: @oMatrix You'll be able to answer it soon; it's just a delay, not a prohibition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way. For those who want to know, as Lubuntu uses LXDE desktop, it has some methods to do things like it. The command for locking the screen is lxlock.